# need some guide with javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my current code it will disable all the `textboxes` with a `class(number)` if all is `empty`....i want to do is even other textboxes with class(number) is empty but others are no empty it will remove the disable attribute in the submit button...and if all textboxes are empty again the disable attribute will activate again.

the problem is it will only remove disable attribute in the submit button if all textboxes with class(number) are not empty...i want it to remove disable attribute even some textboxes are empty.

html code:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" class="number" value="" readonly />
<input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" class="number" value="3" readonly />
<input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" class="number" value="3" readonly />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" disabled />
```

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.number').on('input', function () {
        $('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim(this.value));
    });

    $('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim($('.number').val()));
});
</script>
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: try to give a proper title for your question .... title shoud describe the question in a single line...by this you can attract more people to solve the exact querry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim($('.number').val()));` with:

```
$('.number').each(function() {
    if ($.trim(this.value).length) {
        $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
        return;
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/vDuSj/2).

Comment: @user3340637 The JSFiddle demo works fine... What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(function() {  
    var numberBox=$('.number'),
        button=$('#send'),
        checkEmpty=function(){
            return numberBox.filter(function(){
                return this.value=="";
            }).length!=0;
        };
    numberBox.on('input', function () {
       button.prop("disabled", checkEmpty);
    });

    button.prop("disabled", checkEmpty);
});
```